# Using multiple Stripe checkout buttons, all items use last items price and name on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm working on a simple store front, and wanted to use stripe checkout buttons for the items. I have a DB of items that I'm iterating through, and generating payment buttons for with JS, here's that code:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'stripeForm' do -%>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

  <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeAmount' %>

  <p>
    <% puts p.name %>
      <% @price= p.price %>
      Buy <% p.name %> for <% number_to_currency(@price, :unit=> '$') %>
      <button id="<%=p.id %>">Purchase: <%=p.name%></button>
  </p>

  <script>

    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
      image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function(token, args) {
        $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
        $("#stripeAmount").val('<%= @price %>');
        $("#stripeForm").submit();
      }
    });


      document.getElementById('<%= p.id %>').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      handler.open({
        name: 'Malus Cider',
        description: '<%=p.name%>',
        shippingAddress:true,
        billingAddress:true,
        amount: <%= @price %>
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
      handler.close();
    });

  </script>
```

<% end %>
  <% end %>
my controller:

```
def create
    # Amount in cents

    amount = params[:stripeAmount].to_i * 100

    puts amount

    # Create the customer in Stripe
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: params[:stripeEmail],
      source: params[:stripeToken]

    )

    # Create the charge using the customer data returned by Stripe API
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: amount,
      description: 'Rails Stripe customer',
      currency: 'usd'
    )       
end

private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :price)
  end
```

this works! Except that at the last second the hidden field values change to the last item in the DB. So it almost works. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please fix up the indentation and add in the missing `end`s? It's a little tricky to read as is.

Comment: is that any better?